# Get all possible multiplication values between two arrays in O(n)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, nested, multiplication

In a sequence of number starting at (n>0) I need to find two numbers that when multiplied by each other return the same value as the sum of the sequence less the sum of those numbers (sum - (x+y)). I already have one program written, but I believe is not efficient enough.Is there a way of getting the same result without nesting loops?
Here is my code:

```
function removeNb (n) {

result = [];
var sum = (n*(n+1))/2

for(var x=n; x > 0; x--){
  for(var y = 1; y<=x; y++){

  z= x*y;
  var r = sum-(y+x);

  if(z == r){
  result.push([y,x],[x,y])} *//because with inverted loops (y++, x--) only unique values are left.*
  }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: Do some maths. You're given the `sum` and one of the numbers (say `x`). Can you determine a `y` (or multiple ones) that solves your equation *without trying out*?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution so far has O(n^2). As far as I see the sequence is not a random one. It is the sequence 1, 2, 3 ... N. I assumed that from following line sum = (n*(n+1)) / 2.

Now let's look at the equation r = z which is actually x*y = sum - x - y. You can make a single loop iterating over x from 1 to n and calculate y. Y = (sum - x) / (x +1). If y is equal or less than N so you have a solution(x,y). Using this approach you will make a single loop and you complexity will be O(n).

You can also precompute values and store tham as array as well. This solution is useful if n is in some small range.